# Se cierra script de gulp despues de finalizar

Tags: javascript, nodejs, npm, gulp

Buen día comunidad.
Estoy creando un script en gulp, para que me convierta archivos scss a css. Me funciona como quiero, pero cuando ejecuto el gulp se cierra después de finalizar la última sentencia, sin que yo lo haya solicitado (ctrl+c). Este es mi código gulp

```
    const gulp = require('gulp'),
      sass = require('gulp-sass'),
      autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
      minifiCSS = require('gulp-minify-css'),
      concat = require('gulp-concat');


gulp.task('scss-task', () => {
  return gulp.src('./themes/Qwantika/scss/*.scss').
          pipe(sass({
            outputStyle: 'compressed',
            sourceComments: true
          })).
          pipe(autoprefixer()).
          pipe(concat('style.css')).
          pipe(minifiCSS()).
          pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'))
});

gulp.task('watch', () => {
  gulp.watch('themes/Qwantika/scss/*.scss', gulp.series('scss-task'));
})

gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('scss-task'));
```

Esto es lo que me aparece en consola

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco toda la ayuda que me puedan proporcionar

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo resolví. Me faltaba la respuesta `watch` en la tarea `default`

```
gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('scss-task', 'watch'));
```

Esto hace un watch para cuando se trabaja con SCSS con gulp.

Comment: _Esta respuesta se reportó como de baja calidad debido a su extensión y contenido_ (sí, ¡después de dos años!) Pulsa en [edit] para agregar más detalles a tu respuesta, y no olvides [aceptarla](/help/accepted-answer).